# Prevent file upload by file extension on IIS 10

Tags: iis

I would like to prevent web site users to upload some types of files like .zip, .rar, .bat etc...

Looking for general solution that would be applied to IIS server and not to CMS sistems installed on server.

Uploading .zip file should return an error.

Comment: Go to the folder in IIS and in the "File Name Extensions" tab of the "Request filtering" feature, add "Deny file extension" rules for the file extensions that you want to lock. Then Open the Web.config file from the same directory add the extension and set allowed to false or FSRM (File Server Resource Manager) https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2008/08/20/the-basics-of-windows-server-2008-fsrm-file-server-resource-manager/

Comment: Request filtering option in IIS does not prevent upload of files. It only prevents download this kind of files. Will try with FSRM and report back.

Comment: We need more details about how uploads are occurring to help with this.

Comment: Files are uploaded over installed CMS sistems like Wordpress or DNN... FSRM option works awesome.

Answer (score 0):

- you can add and install "File server resource manager" in windows server (from add/remove programs. Bottom link describe all you needed)
- and then block all extension group(like executable files or videos file) of specific path(in your case specific path is your upload folder)

follow [this link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2008/08/20/the-basics-of-windows-server-2008-fsrm-file-server-resource-manager/) to more details